# Pyomo: Value Error: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object fo[1,1_C1]

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, constraints, pyomo

This link https://github.com/amianAA/ALNS contains an ALNS algorithm which was written to optimise MINLP railroad network models (applied to Madrid's network). Though the comments were written in spanish but I believe that wont be much problem since google translate would be of help in this regard. When I ran the ALNP.py file, it worked perfectly until this stage of the code in the madridALNS.py file wherein the whole model was developed with the aid of Pyomo:

```
 #1 // output flow from each origin "wo" equal to demand of the destination origin pair "w"
 def resd1_rule(model,w):
    wo=model.tabla[w,'wo']
    expr=0
    for l in model.L:
        if model.b[wo,l]==1:
            expr += model.fo[w,l]
        if expr!=0:
            return (expr + model.h[w]==model.tabla[w,'g']*model.factorg)
        else:
            return Constraint.Skip
 model.restr1 = Constraint(model.W,rule=resd1_rule)
```

The madridALNS.dat file contains data for fill of the model. The error I immediately encountered was:

```
 ERROR: evaluating expression: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object
fo[1,1_C1]
    (expression: fo[1,1_C1] + fo[1,2_C2] + fo[1,7_C10] + fo[1,3_C3] +
    fo[1,4_C4] + fo[1,6_C8])
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: fo[1,1_C1] + fo[1,2_C2] +
fo[1,7_C10] + fo[1,3_C3] + fo[1,4_C4] + fo[1,6_C8]
    (object: <class 'pyomo.core.kernel.expr_coopr3._SumExpression'>)
No value for uninitialized NumericValue object fo[1,1_C1]
ERROR: evaluating expression: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object
fo[1,1_C1]
    (expression: fo[1,1_C1] + fo[1,2_C2] + fo[1,7_C10] + fo[1,3_C3] +
    fo[1,4_C4] + fo[1,6_C8]  ==  0.0)
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint restr1 with index
1: ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object fo[1,1_C1]
ERROR: Constructing component 'restr1' from data=None failed:
    ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object fo[1,1_C1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ALNS.py", line 16, in <module>
instance = model.create_instance('madridALNS.dat')
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/PyomoModel.py", line 723, in create_instance
profile_memory=profile_memory )
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/PyomoModel.py", line 806, in load
profile_memory=profile_memory)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/PyomoModel.py", line 870, in _load_model_data
self._initialize_component(modeldata, namespaces, component_name, profile_memory)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/PyomoModel.py", line 925, in _initialize_component
declaration.construct(data)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/constraint.py", line 793, in construct
ndx)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/misc.py", line 61, in apply_indexed_rule
return rule(model, index)
 File "/home/bunmalik/Desktop/project/codes/codes/ALNS/ALNS-master/madridALNS.py", line 120, in resd1_rule
if expr!=0:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/kernel/expr_coopr3.py", line 533, in __nonzero__
return bool(self())
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/kernel/expr_coopr3.py", line 208, in __call__
exception=exception))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/kernel/expr_coopr3.py", line 545, in _apply_operation
return next(values) == next(values)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/kernel/expr_coopr3.py", line 217, in _evaluate_arglist
yield value(arg, exception=exception)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/kernel/numvalue.py", line 161, in value
tmp = numeric(exception=exception)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/kernel/expr_coopr3.py", line 208, in __call__
exception=exception))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/kernel/expr_coopr3.py", line 812, in _apply_operation
return sum(c*next(values) for c in self._coef) + self._const
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/kernel/expr_coopr3.py", line 812, in <genexpr>
return sum(c*next(values) for c in self._coef) + self._const
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/kernel/expr_coopr3.py", line 217, in _evaluate_arglist
yield value(arg, exception=exception)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyomo/core/kernel/numvalue.py", line 170, in value
% (obj.name,))
```

I am solving similar optimization problem in my project work. However, I am new to Pyomo. Please could someone come to my aid to resolve the error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Two comments with this model:

1. The immediate issue is that the stack trace implicates the `if expr!=0:` line. Here, the inequality operator makes Pyomo evaluate the value of `expr`. Since some of the variables involved in the expression are uninitialized and do not have values, the `No value for uninitialized NumericValue object` error is observed.
2. I hope that `model.b[wo,l]` is a parameter. If it is a variable, then you might be trying to express disjunctive logic within a Constraint declaration, which is not typically supported within an algebraic modeling language. For more on that, you'll want to look into Pyomo.GDP. If it is a parameter, then you're fine as is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Qi Chen, **model.b[wo,1]** is a parameter. But the initialization is the problem. I commented out this constraint and tested the others, I got the same error. Meanwhile when I ""pprinted"" the instance of the model, all the declarations was shown!

Comment: I'm surprised. You say that the stack trace is identical even if you comment out this constraint?

Comment: Yes @Oi, This was the error I got for the third constraint **restr3**: __ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object trans[2_N_Ministerios,1,1_C1,3_C3]__. Again the Traceback implicates the 'if (expr2+expr3)!=0 and (expr1+expr4)!=0:' line. I agree the problem may be from the uninitialization of some variables, but I cant figure where exactly! Please could you run the files at your end and see if you would get same problem. Perhaps the problem was from my end.

Comment: Perhaps try `expr is 0` so that the coercion to `value()` doesn't happen for the expression.

Comment: Wow! this worked like magic. Thanks so much @Qi. Please I need clarity on the difference between **!=** and **is not**. But I got a different error again causing another headache. I'm gonna open another Stackoverflow question. Thumbs up!